# Is there a method that i can get a list of ip addreses of clients currently connected to the server?

Tags: java, sockets

Is there a method that i can get a list of ip addreses of clients currently connected to the server ? Or can i get the number of clients connected to the server in java socket connections?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getRemoteSocketAdress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getRemoteSocketAddress%28%29) method from the `Socket` class. Like this:

```
String remoteAddress = mySocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
```

To retrieve the remote addresses for every one of the client, you have to apply this to every client socket thread.